# undefined reference to `VSIInstallCurlStreamingFileHandler'

Tags: cmake, ros, gdal

I've met the following error when executing `make` in my project "open_data_driver". The command `cmake .` finished successfully:

> CMakeFiles/open_data_driver.dir/src/Geoportale.cpp.o: In function
>   'Geoportale::Geoportale()': Geoportale.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined
>   reference to `VSIInstallCurlStreamingFileHandler'

Code of `Geoportale.cpp` is the following:

```
/*
 * Geoportale.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 14, 2014
 *      Author: enrico
 */

#include <climits>
#include </home/mikkita/odomi-master/open_data_driver/include/opendata/Geoportale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "/home/mikkita/odomi-master/open_data_driver/include/read/read.h"
#include "/home/mikkita/usr_include_gdal/gdal/cpl_port.h"

#include "/usr/include/gdal/cpl_vsi_virtual.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdal/cpl_string.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdal/cpl_multiproc.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdal/cpl_hash_set.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdal/cpl_time.h"
#include </usr/include/curl/curl.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "/home/mikkita/catkin_ws/include/geometry_msgs/Polygon.h"
#include "/home/mikkita/catkin_ws/devel/include/open_data_msg/Data.h"
#include "/home/mikkita/catkin_ws/devel/include/open_data_msg/Open_data.h" 
#include "/home/mikkita/odomi-master/open_data_driver/include/opendata/ogr_geos.h"


Geoportale::Geoportale() {
    VSIInstallCurlStreamingFileHandler();
} 

Geoportale::~Geoportale() {}

/*Other code*/
```

Code of the `CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(open_data_driver)

find_library(CURL_LIBRARY curl /usr/bin/curl.so)
find_library(GDAL_LIBRARY gdal /usr/lib/libgdal.so) ####MikkiTA
find_library(ZZIP_LIBRARY zzip /usr/lib/libzzip.so)
find_library(MYSQLCLIENT_LIBRARY mysqlclient /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so)
find_library(MYSQLZ_LIBRARY z /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so)
find_library(curl_LIBRARIES curl /usr/bin/curl.so) ##MikkiTA
find_library(gdal_LIBRARIES gdal /usr/lib/libgdal.so) ####MikkiTA
find_library(zzip_LIBRARIES zzip /usr/lib/libzzip.so) ##MikkiTA

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
    #open_data_msg
    geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES open_data_driver
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
    DEPENDS curl gdal zzip
)

include_directories(include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${curl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${gdal_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${zzip_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${mysql_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${z_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

add_library(geoportale
    src/Geoportale.cpp
    src/read.cpp
    src/Json/json_reader.cpp
    src/Json/json_value.cpp
    src/Json/json_writer.cpp
) ##MikkiTA delete src/Oggetto.cpp
target_link_libraries(geoportale
    ${CURL_LIBRARY}
    ${GDAL_LIBRARY}
)

add_executable(open_data_driver
    src/open_data_driver.cpp
    src/read.cpp
    src/Json/json_reader.cpp
    src/Json/json_value.cpp
    src/Json/json_writer.cpp
    src/Geoportale.cpp
    src/Trasporti.cpp
    src/Csv/csv_parser.cpp
    src/PotenzaSegnale.cpp
    src/Traffico.cpp
    src/Weather.cpp
    src/xml/pugixml.cpp
)
add_dependencies(open_data_driver
    ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
target_link_libraries(open_data_driver
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    #${CURL_LIBRARY} ${ZZIP_LIBRARY} ${ZZIP_LIBRARY}
)
target_link_libraries(open_data_driver
    curl
    gdal
    zzip
    mysqlclient
    z
)
target_link_libraries(open_data_driver
    ${GDAL_LIBRARY}
) ##MikkiTA
target_link_libraries(open_data_driver
    geoportale
)  ##MikkiTA

add_executable(bounding_box_client
    src/client.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(bounding_box_client
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(open_data_sync
    src/open_data_sync.cpp
    src/Trasporti.cpp
    src/Csv/csv_parser.cpp
    src/read.cpp
)
add_dependencies(open_data_driver
    ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
target_link_libraries(open_data_sync
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
target_link_libraries(open_data_sync
    curl
    zzip
    mysqlclient
    z
)
```

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?
GDAL 2.1.3 is installed.

Comment: Your `CMakeLists.txt` is a little confusing: You have a `find_library` twice for each lib. You have multiple `target_link_libraries` for the same target. Sometimes, you use the `xxx_LIBRARY` variable for linking, sometimes the plain library name. I suggest that you first clean up these things, which may already reveal a solution for your problem.

Comment: Properly changed CMakeLists.txt can be found here: https://github.com/fly4smartcity/odomi/blob/master/open_data_driver/CMakeLists.txt

But unfortunately I still have the same problem

Comment: The only thing I've changed there is that I commented  "open_data_msg" in find_package block. Otherwise cmake . is not making without a mistakes.